# Dapper - Bulk insert of new items and get back new IDs

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, dapper, bulkinsert

I am using dapper to add multiple new students in one db hit using this method:

```
db.ExecuteAsync(@"INSERT Student(Name,Age) values (@Name,@Age)", 
  students.Select(s => new { Name = s.Name, Age = s.Age })
);
```

But the problem I don't have the new ids.

Can I make one db hit and still some how get the new ids ?
And if not, what is the most efficient way of performing such bulk insert ?

Comment: As an aside; you don't need to do the `.Select(...)`; it would work just as well with just `db.Execute[Async]("...", students)`. It does some basic regex checks to identify which properties might be useful - it won't add every property as a parameter. Except for stored procedures ;p

Answer (score 5):

That is *not* a bulk insert; it is basically just shorthand that unrolls the loop; although interestingly (perhaps) it *is* possible to ask it to *pipeline* that sequence *if* "MARS" is enabled on your connection. Without the pipeline, it is *basically* shorthand for:

```
foreach(var obj in students.Select(s => new { Name = s.Name, Age = s.Age }))
{
    await db.ExecuteAsync(@"INSERT Student(Name,Age) values (@Name,@Age)", obj);
}
```

in which case, you might as well use `Query` or `ExecuteScalar` to fetch the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

*With* the pipeline, it is more subtle; it does the same thing, but with multiple outstanding commands at a time (it only `await`s when the backlog is full, or when all of the commands have been issued).

Bulk insert does not return ids. You *could* consider using a table valued parameter and using `INSERT` with the `OUTPUT` clause to insert an entire `DataTable` of data at a time (getting the identities in the process), but on the negative side: *it does involve using `DataTable`* ;p

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Dapper Plus](https://dapper-plus.net/)

As Marc answered, there is no `BulkInsert` in Dapper.

However, it's possible to achieve it with Dapper Plus (The library is commercial)

You need to specify in the mapping which column is an identity (so the id get populated on the entity automatically)

```
// MAP once
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Invoice>().Identity(x => x.InvoiceID);

connection.BulkInsert(invoices, x => x.InvoiceMeta, x => x.InvoiceItems);
```

It even possible to propagate automatically the identity by specifying the identity propagation to `true`

```
// MAP once
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Invoice>().Identity(x => x.InvoiceID, true);

connection.BulkInsert(invoices, x => x.InvoiceMeta, x => x.InvoiceItems);
```

In this case, `InvoiceItem` will automatically have the `InvoiceID` also populated.

You can learn more about identity propagation here: https://dapper-plus.net/getting-started-identity-propagation