# Dapper throws "Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod."

Tags: c#, dapper

So I'm trying to use Dapper.net and I'm liking it. What I'm not liking is when I try to batch-insert entities and I get the following error thrown:

**Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod.**

> at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.Init(String name,
>   MethodAttributes attributes, CallingConventions callingConvention,
>   Type returnType, Type[] signature, Type owner, Module m, Boolean
>   skipVisibility, Boolean transparentMethod, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type
>   returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner, Boolean skipVisibility)
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.CreateParamInfoGenerator(Identity identity,
>   Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean removeUnused, IList`1 literals) in
>   D:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 3033    at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.GetCacheInfo(Identity identity, Object
>   exampleParameters, Boolean addToCache) in D:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper
>   NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 2138    at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__61`1.MoveNext() in
>   D:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1578    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param,
>   IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in
>   D:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1479    at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param,
>   IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in
>   D:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1418    at
>   NinjaEvaluation.Data.Database.DapperWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.b__3(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction) in
>   c:\Projects\InHouse\ninjaevaluation\NinjaEvaluation\NinjaEvaluation.Data\Database\DapperWrapper.cs:line
>   52    at NinjaEvaluation.Data.Database.DapperWrapper.Invoke(Action`2
>   action) in
>   c:\Projects\InHouse\ninjaevaluation\NinjaEvaluation\NinjaEvaluation.Data\Database\DapperWrapper.cs:line
>   68

This happens in a completely normal situation when I run my query like this:

```
        string sql = @" INSERT INTO XXX
                        (XXXId, AnotherId, ThirdId, Value, Comment)
                        VALUES
                        (@XXXId, @AnotherId, @ThirdId, @Value, @Comment)";

        var parameters = command
            .MyModels
            .Select(model => new
            {
                XXXId= model.XXXId,
                AnotherId= model.AnotherId,
                ThirdId= model.ThirdId,
                Value = model.Value,
                Comment = model.Comment
            })
            .ToArray();
```

...

```
sqlConnection.Query(sql, parameters, commandType: commandType, transaction: transaction)
```

I found [the following SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705325/dapper-execute-a-command-multiple-times-and-linq-and-toarray) started by someone having the same problem BUT the issue there seems to have been the .NET version (3.5) but I'm running .NET 4.5 and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder - is this a restricted trust environment? Or regular .net with nothing special?

Comment: Regular local environment. No restrictions at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It fails because this scenario using `Query[<T>]` isn't expecting an array / sequence of parameters. The `Execute` call-path *does* expect this, and unrolls the data automatically, executing the SQL once per item - but this isn't the case for `Query[<T>]`, so it tries to create the dynamic method bound to the *array* (in your case), which isn't allowed. The code should probably detect this much earlier, and just say "nope, that isn't allowed".

You *probably* want to change your `.ToArray()` to `.Single()`.

This will be clearer after the next build;  the following passes:

```
    public void SO30435185_InvalidTypeOwner()
    {
        try {
            // not shown for brevity: something very similar to your code
            Assert.Fail();
        } catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            ex.Message.IsEqualTo("An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should've used Execute :)

Comment: @Maffelu heh, or that ;p

Comment: Is this a shortcoming of Dapper, or does it logically not make sense to query with a sequence of parameters? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39884768) is interested in selecting the IDs of inserted rows, which is not possible in the current state of Dapper. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29615445) Implies it *used to* work - the first snippet - or is their error related to this? To me it would seem that if `Execute` can handle a sequence of parameters, `Query` should be able to as well. The best workaround I can come up with involves 4 separate queries, which isn't ideal

Comment: @Rob well, where the loop appears isn't going to make a huge difference to the actual operations; yes, we could make `Query` work with a sequence and essentially concatenate the results, but would it be any clearer?

Answer (score 42):

I ran into this error when using an interface instead of the class:

`Query<MyObject>` worked, while `Query<IMyObject>` did not

Comment: Same as me I ran into this error when using an interface instead of the class: Query<MyObject> worked, while Query<IMyObject> did not. you should ensure that you use the class type on the return value for the executing command, not Interface.

Comment: My issue was basically the same, but when trying to retrieve a list of objects, I mistakenly wrote `Query<IEnumerable<MyObject>>` instead of `Query<MyObject>`