# Why is Dapper unable to return multiple inserted row ids?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

I have a SQL Server table into which rows are inserted using:

```
var sql = @"
DECLARE @InsertedRows AS TABLE (Id BIGINT);
INSERT INTO Person ([Name], [Age]) OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @InsertedRows
VALUES (@Name, @Age);
SELECT Id FROM @InsertedRows;";

Person person = ...;

var id = connection.Query<long>(sql, person).First();
```

This all works well however if I try to insert multiple items and return all the inserted ids using:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = ...;    
var ids = connection.Query<long>(sql, people);
```

I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetCacheInfo(Identity identity, Object exampleParameters,  Boolean addToCache)
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__23`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

How would one return multiple inserted ids in Dapper?

Comment: Not experienced with dapper but it looks like you are telling it you are expecting one `long`. Try some kind of collection like `..Query<List<long>>..`

Comment: `Query<T>` does return `IEnumerable<T>` hence the use of `First()` on the first query.

Comment: I see. Maybe you have to map it to a class that has a `long` property named `Id`

Comment: `Person` does indeed have an `Id` of type `long` otherwise the first query would not be successful so it must be something else.

Comment: The question isn't really whether or not Dapper supports returning multiple row IDs, it's actually 'How do I get multiple row IDs after inserting?'. It simply executes the SQL you give it. You're wanting the `INSERT` SQL to execute multiple times (depending on `people`), but the final select to execute once. That would require Dapper to have knowledge about the SQL you're executing, which it doesn't. Think about how you'd do this without Dapper (just in plain SQL), and you'll find what you're trying to do doesn't quite make sense - you need multiple insert statements

Comment: Actually that is not true, dapper knows how to map IEnumerable<T> to the escaped SQL, so comparing it to how you would do this using plain SQL is irrelevant. You can try this out yourself by replacing the `sql` with: `INSERT INTO Person ([Name], [Age]) VALUES (@Name, @Age);` and executing it with `SqlMapper.Execute()` you will see all the items inserted correctly.

Comment: @MaYaN Yes, for `Execute`, not for `Query`

Comment: If I am not wrong the error refers to the parameter passed to  _connection.Query_  It doesn't accept an IEnumerable<T> as parameter. You should try with _connection.Execute_ (but I could be very wrong)

Comment: @Rob, I see what you mean now. hmm... I would expect it to run the query as: `DECLARE @InsertedRows AS TABLE (Id BIGINT);
INSERT INTO Person ([Name], [Age]) OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @InsertedRows
VALUES (@Name1, @Age1),(@Name2, @Age2),...;
SELECT Id FROM @InsertedRows;";` which does indeed work using plain SQL. In that case how would one achieve the same goal in _Dapper_?

Comment: @MaYaN I believe the best way to do so would be to have separate queries: 1. Create a temp table (rather than just a variable). Run the insert as `Execute` rather than `Query`, and OUTPUT into the temp table. Run `Query` against the temp table, and then drop the temp table. To me, this doesn't seem ideal, but I'm struggling to think of a better way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something, somewhere, needs to loop. You have a sql statement that inserts one row, and code sending in a list. Since you like your SQL in string literals, I would stick to inserting one person at a time, putting the loop in the C# and recovering each id in the C# using `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. You no longer need @InsertedRows, or OUTPUT.

If you really want to loop in SQL, I believe you'll need to look at table valued parameters for passing your list of inserts. Dapper is very happy to return multiple Ids. It's complaining about multiple people as an input parameter.

One day, hopefully soon, we're going to look back at SQL in string literals like we presently look at [goat sacrifice](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb).

Comment: Valid for `INSERT Production.[TestScrapReason] (Name)  
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate  
SELECT [Name]  FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Production].[ScrapReason]` ?